# Query to retrieve documents associated with language other than english

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

We have documents in our ML DB associated to different language other than english.
Language assigned to a document using attribute @xml:lang in root element.

e.g.

```
a.xml
<article xml:lang="es">
  abc
</article>

b.xml
<article xml:lang="it">
  abc
</article>
```

full text search gives empty result unless language option is specified in cts:word-query.

It require to specify the lang option in word query to get the corresponding xml data in search result.
e.g.

```
cts:search(/article, cts:word-qyery("abc", "lang=es"))
```

the problem is it allows one lang option in one word query.

Is it possible to build a query which can search this record associated to different language without specifying lang option in cts:word-query.

So that we can implement full text search for these documents.

Any suggestion or thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks
AK

Answer (score 2):

If you make it an unstemmed word-query and then you don't have to specify a language. That just runs a basic word match, which it sounds like you want. If you use stemming (which is the default if you have the stemming index enabled, which I presume you do), then the language matters because stemming only makes sense in the context of a language.

```
cts:search(/article, cts:word-query("abc", "unstemmed"))
```